# Reading json data from php script to android app is working on android app but not on real device

Tags: android

I am new in android i am using php web api to transfer data from app to mysql in xampp but getting json data works fine on emulator showing correct data but on real device it is not showing anything . Where is the issue??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection =null;
    try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int data = reader.read();
        while (data!=-1)
        {
            char current = (char)data;
            result+=current;
            data=reader.read();
        }
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Error",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s!=null)
            {
                try{

                    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
                    t.setText(s);

                }
                catch (Exception a)
                {
                  Log.e("Error",a.getMessage());
                }
        }}
    }
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
            downloadTask.execute("http://192.168.0.69:8082/AndroidData/sample.php");
    }
    }
```

Comment: check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/1712446

Comment: I have tried that too but it didn't work that's why I posted this question

Comment: is your real device connected on same network of pc?

Comment: Yes they both are on the same network .

Comment: try opening the url "http://192.168.0.69:8082/AndroidData/sample.php" in your device and check if it works, can please show your logcat

Comment: Mylogcat is 2020-01-31 12:24:54.037 6493-6493/com.example.workwithjson I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-01-31 12:24:54.098 6493-6493/com.example.workwithjson W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-01-31 12:24:54.340 6493-6527/com.example.workwithjson D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2020-01-31 12:24:54.356 6493-6524/com.example.workwithjson D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-01-31 12:24:54.393 6493-6527/com.example.workwithjson I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfa